# Laser 'receiver' for MCU

Tags: arduino, laser-diode

I need to send data over a wireless link, not far - max 50m. I have plenty of laser diodes, 1-5mW, with glass lenses that can be adjusted. I would rather avoid buying a 'receiver', since I can probably build one faster than it can be shipped. I understand that LEDs can generate a few microamps when hit with a weak laser beam. What's the best colour LED for this? And what's the best way to build a minimal amplifier? 
I would prefer not using an op-amp.

My MCU responds to 3V3 and 5V, though I can probably make use of 1-2V as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is probably not going to work. Some leds can generate some current, but with those small currents also the capacitance of the led has influence. Try a photodiode. I think the lower colors are sensitive for that color and for higher colors. Blue is sensitive for blue. Red is sensitive for Red, Green, Blue.

Comment: @Jot Will do. Post it as an answer please.

Comment: Any transceiver design MUST include specs for data rate, BER error rate, line of site, beam angle and wavelength then sensitivity in terms of uA/uW of signal after Friss Loss calculations ( inverse square loss) Then understand you need high gain and high impedance to receive low current which with a diode that has self capacitance results in an RC = 0.35/f slew rate limit, thus forcing you to consider a video amp or high GBW TIA amp configuration.

Comment: It's just output from a serial port at 9600 baud, amplified with a 2N3904 NPN. Known to work fine, even up to 115200 baud with a proper design. Can't use cable for this.

Comment: I've posted several logarithmic-compression TIA circuits within the last few months.

Comment: Do you have precision aiming apparatus, or will the laser just flood the receiver area?  How do you plan to exclude stray light, and what happens if a moth flies through the light path?

Comment: "I need to build a car.  No transmission allowed, and I have these round rocks I'd like to use as wheels."

Comment: Flood into a diffuser if necessary due to dot size, or just the photodiode.

Comment: @JRE It's just a serial link, it doesn't have to be cool like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you rather look for photoresistor or phototransistor. It will fit your need more than LED.